# Default Media Receiver support media format types

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

Does the Default Media Receiver support image formats such as jpeg, bmp, gif, etc. and others that are listed on this page:  https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Default Media Receiver supports image formats that are listed there.